# Consuming markdown inside yaml

Tags: middleman

I'm doing my first website with middleman and it's raising up some questions for me. One of which is if this is acceptable or/and the right approach.

My site ir organized like so:

```
data
  about.yml
  carrer.yml
  ...
source
  en
    about
      index.html.erb
    career
      index.html.erb
  ...
config.rb
GemFile
Gemfile.lock
```

I wish to consume the .yml from my html.erb file so inside my yaml  have this:

```
pt:
    slides:
      - url: "/images/url.png"
        markdown: "#Heading One"

      - url: "/images/url.png"
        markdown: "#Heading One"

      - url: "/images/url.png"
        markdown: "#Heading One"
en:
    slides:
      - url: "/images/nocturna_new_lisbon_bridge_2.jpg"
      ---
      markdown:
      #Heading Oness
      ####Heading Four
      ---

      - url: "/images/url.png"
        markdown: "#Heading One"

      - url: "/images/url.png"
        markdown: "#Heading One"
```

No problem on my `pt` version but how can I get to make a more complicated markdown like on the `en` version? It doesn't work...

Finally on my index.html.erb I have somewhere in the page:

```
            <% data.homepage_carousel.en.slides.each_with_index do |f, index| %>
                <div class="item <%='active' if index == 0 %>" style="background-image:url(<%= f.url %>)">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <%= markdown f.markdown %><!-- CALLING HELPER-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

And that is ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this would do it:

```
en:
    slides:
      - url: "/images/nocturna_new_lisbon_bridge_2.jpg"
        markdown: >
          #Heading Oness


          ####Heading Four


...
```

The extra-lines ad spaces were what I was looking for as well as the > at the beginning of the var.